# Efficient duplicates checking for multiple types of objects in Java

Tags: java, performance, list, interface

I'm working on a project where I've got multiple classes to hold data loaded from an xml file. The problem I would like to solve is that almost all of the classes have these methods:

- addSingle[objectName]
- addMultiple[objectName]

However, there may be more types of objects in a class that need to be added this way. For example:

```
    class Airspace {
        private List airports;
        private List waypoints;
    ...
       public void addSingleAirport(Airport a) {...}
       public void addMultipleAirports(Airport[] a {...}
       public void addSingleWaypoint(Waypoint w) {...}
       public void addMultipleWaypoints(Waypoint w) {...}

    }
```

I was thinking of putting those `addSingle` and `addMultiple` methods into an interface and then decide, when implementing the methods, according to the objects type to which list it should be added, but wouldn't that be stupid?

Is there any more efficient way to do this? I want to avoid writing these methods into every class that needs them with the specific objects because they all do exactly the same.

Comment: I forgot to mention that all of those methods check whether the object provided as the parameter exists.

Comment: Loading data from an XML file: it may not the best way to write these JAva classes by hand. There is JAB, for instance, and jc takes care of writing whatever is necessary for adding to lists, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you approach is stupid but it is true this type checking can affect performance.

Nevertheless, expanding your approach, I would keep a map of lists indexed by `Class`:

```
class Airspace {
    private Map<Class, List<Object>> lists = new HashMap();

    public void addSingle(Object o)
    {
        List<Object> list = lists.get(o.getClass());
        if(list == null)
        {
            list = new ArrayList();
            lists.put(o.getClass(), list);
        }
        list.add(o);
    }
...
...
```

Comment: Yes, this is the approach I would recommend too, although first I'd revisit the architecture as this smells rather like something that hasn't been properly thought through.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addAirports(Airport... a ){...}
```

should be able to handle all cases - or did I miss something?

A very general

```
public void addThings( Object... o )
```

can be written, but do you want to lose readability and type checking? Runtime errors if there's no matching Foo-list in an object? Shudder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Abstract class with generics then extends it from you class. Something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractSomeclass<E>{
    public void addObject(E... obj, List<E>){
        //yourcode here 
    }
}
```

Then in your class:

```
public class MyClass extends AbstractSomeclass<Airport>{
    public List<Airport> list; 
    //.....
    public void someMethod(){
        super.addObject( airportObject, list );
    }
}
```

Maybe there is some minor errors (on this code), but hold on with the idea.